# How Can I Create Charts of Expanding Tabular Data in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a set of data that I will be adding rows to on a daily basis, and some charts having data series pointing to the data. The problem I have is that as I add a new row's worth of data to the bottom, the charts do not update to include the new data, as it sees it as being outside the original range.

In Microsoft Excel, there was a concept of a "Table," and creating a chart based on a Table meant that any and all data in the Table – including newly added data – would be added to the charts. The closest thing Google Sheets has is "Named Ranges," and charts cannot reference them.

How can I add a new row such that the charts pointing to the data to the rows above it automatically include the new row too?

Comment: Google Sheets does not have this feature buit-in, unfortunately. However, it might be possible via Apps Script. Are you open to using a workaround that utilizes Apps Script? If you are, please do share a sample sheet showing how the data and charts are configured.

Comment: `The problem I have is that as I add a new row's worth of data to the bottom, the charts do not update to include the new data, as it sees it as being outside the original range.` This is **not** my experience. Regardless of whether ranges are adjacent or separated by other columns, I have found that when new data is added to next row of any data range, the chart automatically adjusts to include the new data. Another approach is to leave the range row dimension 'open' (such as "A1:C"). You haven't shared any data or detail so I can't comment specifically on _your_ chart.